# Joining mysql tables on multiple fields

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-tables

I have a sports site where I have a teams table and a games table.  The teams table has the team id, name, and logo(url). The games table has the game id, date, time, hometeamid, and awayteamid.

I'm trying to come up with a mysql query that will return the list of games that includes the associated team names and logos that go with their ids.

Right now, I'm pulling the list of games with their hometeamid and awayteamid, then I'm going back to do a query on the teams table with the hometeamid to get their name and logo, then repeating with the awayteamid to get their name and logo.

That seems like a lot of hitting the db, especially if I can somehow join them in the one first query.

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have tables:

TEAM with fields T_ID, NAME, URL

GAME with fields G_ID, T_ID1, T_ID2, others...

A joined select in your case would be:

```
Select a.G_ID,b.NAME,c.NAME from GAME a, TEAM b, TEAM c where a.T_ID1=c.T_ID and a.T_ID2=b.T_ID
```

Let us know if you need any more help

Comment: The Fabio, worked perfectly, Thank you very much!

Strawberry, what is the issue, and what is an alternative? 

I just got thrown back into working with advanced queries after being away for about 5 years, and I'm having to relearn quite a bit and delve into things I never needed to before.